# Count if cells contain date in the format of Date & Time

Tags: excel, datetime, countif

I have column in Excel containing Date in the format given below and I want to count the cells having specific data not the time. For instance I want to count cells containing `7/29/2008` in the below data it must give 3. I have tried `=countif(range,"7/29/2008")` but result was 0.

```
7/28/2008  5:28:51 AM
7/29/2008  5:30:53 AM
7/29/2008  5:33:25 AM
7/29/2008  5:38:15 AM
7/30/2008  5:39:36 AM
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

With your data in A2:A6 try this,

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A6, ">="&DATE(2008, 7, 29), A2:A6, "<"&DATE(2008, 7, 30))
```

With 07/29/2008 in B1 this would be,

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A6, ">="&B1, A2:A6, "<"&(B1+1))
```

Answer (score -2):

I was attempting to do this as well.  My problem was trying to extract the date only from datetime formatted cell (using a custom formatting, `m-d-yyyy h:mm`). Internally, dates are stored as Excel date serial numbers in the form of `xxxxx.yyyyyy`.  I tried to find ways of pattern matching, trimming, and extracting formats from the cell range within the formula and was pulling my hair out (what I have left).

Then, I started to discover that if you set the cell value as a date without specifying a time, it would pattern match if the time was also matched.  In this case, without specification, the default time was 12:00 AM.  As soon as I started to match other dates with any other time specified, it would fail.

In my case, this is true: >= of today'sdate and the <= to tomorrow solved the issue based on Excel's default time of midnight (which is used if the time is not specified).